# Asymptotic expansion of the series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{-\cosh[(2n+1)\pi x] + \cos(\theta)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I would like to find the asymptotic expansion of

$$ I(x)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{\sin(\theta)}{-\cosh[(2n+1)\pi x] + \cos(\theta)} $$ when $x \rightarrow 0$. Here $-\pi < \theta < \pi$.
I think that the solution is $$ I(x) \sim \frac{1}{x}( \frac{\theta}{\pi} -1 ) \ (x \rightarrow 0)$$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: *Hint.* Think of $$x I(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta-\cosh[(2n+1)\pi x]}\cdot x$$ as a Riemann sum of some integral, and evaluate the integral to confirm that $$x I(x)\to\left(\frac{\theta}{\pi}-\operatorname{sgn}(\theta)\right).$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks, nice trick ! The integral was a bit difficult but I managed to solve it.

Comment: An interesting integral :) Denoting $I(\beta)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin\theta \,e^{\beta x}}{\cos\theta-\cosh x}dx \,(0<\theta<\pi)$ and integrating along a rectangular contour $C$ in the complex plane $(-R; \,R; \,R+2\pi i; \,-R+2\pi i;\,-R)$
$$\frac1{2\pi}\oint_C\frac{\sin\theta \,e^{\beta z}}{\cos\theta-\cosh z}dz=I(1-e^{2\pi i\beta})=\frac{2\pi i}{2\pi}\underset{\binom{z=i\theta}{z=2\pi i-i\theta}}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\sin\theta \,e^{\beta z}}{\cos\theta-\cosh z}$$
$$I(\beta)=\frac{\sin\beta(\theta-\pi)}{\sin\pi\beta}\to\frac\theta\pi-1\,\,\text{at}\,\,\beta\to 0$$

Comment: The summation has a closed form in terms of the q-polygamma function.

After simplifications, at least for $x>0$,
$$I(x)=\frac i{\pi x}\, \left(\psi _{e^{2 \pi  x}}^{(0)}\left(\frac 12+\frac{i \theta }{2 \pi 
   x}\right)-\psi _{e^{2 \pi 
   x}}^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \theta }{2 \pi 
   x}\right)\right)$$ but the expansion does not seem to be easy (at least for me)

Comment: @Svyatoslav Much simpler than what I had done, thank you !